# Is there an official implementation for C++ bit flags?

Tags: c++

I read the following in the  "Make interfaces precisely and strongly typed" section of [C++ Core Guidelines, I.4](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i4-make-interfaces-precisely-and-strongly-typed):

> "For the case of a set of boolean values consider using a flags enum;
> a pattern that expresses a set of boolean values."

So it seems as if there is supposed to be a standard way to do this. For example, the idea of using scoped enums (in C++11 and up) sounds interesting. However, it doesn't seem like any implementation is really official, and every attempt gets some criticism. What is the standard here?

Comment: `enum { A = 0x0001, B = 0x0002, C = 0x0004, ...} Flags`. No 'official implementation' required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are enums the canonical way to implement bit flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251427/are-enums-the-canonical-way-to-implement-bit-flags)

Comment: "Better off if such implementation doesn't use the STL (some C++ compilers doesn't even include it)." - that makes no sense; "STL" hasn't been a thing [since the mid-90s](http://www.stlport.org/doc/sgi_stl.html). It's sometimes used inaccurately as a nickname for the **C++ standard library**; I have no idea what compilers you've encountered that don't provide that - especially if they're pretending to implement C++11, or any other actual standard.

Comment: Anyway, I removed that along with the rest of my editing. Please try to keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; posts here should be **questions** that are **directly** about **the code, not** you, your personal perspective as an embedded developer, etc.

Comment: I use `enum class` for the bit flags, and provide the operations (via operator overload) for the way I want the bit flags to allowed to be manipulated (usually `operator|` for combining and `operator&` for masking, and by my own convention unary `operator+` to convert to its underlying type).

Comment: An enumeration is one common way to do things. The basic thing to keep in mind is that you want to give names that will be meaningful to a user. If you have something like `x = file(name, true);` it's pretty hard for anybody to guess what `true` means in this case. Changing that to an enumeration like `x = file(name, EnableSharing);` makes the meaning of the second parameter obvious. A `bool` can be meaningful, but something else is usually better, especially if there are two or more such parameters (e.g., consider `foo(true, false, true)` vs. `foo(true, true, false)`).

Comment: But also note that scoped enumerations aren't a panacea either. Especially if you want to be able to combine them with bitwise `or`, (e.g., like `open_file(..., read | binary)` a scoped enumeration may cause more harm than good. It often makes sense to use a normal enumeration that's a public member of the class, so that would still be something like `file::read | file::binary)`.

Comment: @user207421, my question is towards scoped enums implemented since C++11. It's a new data type that doesn't mix with integers (unless you casting them).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, It's not my personal view on ES, it's a fact: AVR compiler last release (from 2017) does implement C++17, however, STL isn't available, that's way I would like to know if there exist an official implementation out of the STL.

Comment: @Eljay, The problem is when you want to discriminate individually your bit flags inside a switch statement, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32579209/1496939

Comment: A `switch` statement is the wrong tool for the bitflags job.

Comment: @FranciscoRodríguez what I am trying to tell you is that the phrasing "STL is/isn't available" doesn't make any sense in the first place.